# How would I go about pulling data from a website using Python?

Tags: python, module

In reference towards me question, how would one be able to input data and retrieve data from various websites (not using an API)?

Is there a module that searches or acts like a human for purposes as in searching along applicably given fields; in effort to (as said before) retrieve data?

Sorry if I'm making my question hard to follow along; though if so, here's an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

- [Directing an AI towards a specific website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRaO2.png).
- [Inputting data into the search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRNz1.png).
- [Then finally, retrieving said data after previously ran processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pajuL.png).

I'm fairly new to the section or field in manipulating websites via APIs or various (unknown) code; therefore, sorry if I missed anything!

Comment: You should re-write your question. What your looking for is [gui automation](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui). That is the only way if your not using something like scrapy

Comment: To act the most like a human, control a real browser using Selenium.

Comment: @IronManMark20 Ah that makes sense; you see, I was completely lost on what that designated field was called. Though now that I know, I may begin my research . . . thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

mechanize,
BeautifulSoup,
Urllib,
Urllib2,

modules in Python. What I suggest you is use mechanize module. It is like scraping website through python program. More over simply a browser through python code.